# How Do I know depth of a Retweet with Jtwitter?

Tags: java, depth, jtwitter

I want  finding the depth of a retwwet with Jtwitter, but the status always show RT @user, as always show of tweet source and I want Knowing when a tweet has been retweeting of this manner:

user1: tweet

user2 retweeting tweet of user1 (the status show: RT @user1)

user3 retweeting retweet of user2 (the status show: RT @user1)

user4 retweeting retweet of user3 (the status show: RT @user1)

user5 retweeting retweet of user4 (the status show: RT @user1)

for can knowing the depth of a retweet if show always the same user despite the retweet is to another user. If anyone knows a method for this I would appreciate

Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that information isn't provided by Twitter.

This is because, with new-style retweets, what's displayed to user 3 is just user 1's tweet (with an overlay saying why). So what user 1 retweets is the original tweet.

With old-style retweets, you'll sometimes see status text "RT @user2: RT @user1: ..." in which case it's simple to work out the chain.

Comment: So, finally there isn't exist any method to track down from whom user, twitter users retweet??RT @user2